# Illustrator: "the selection contains objects which can't be distorted"-error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I am trying to make a distort effect in illustrator. I use the white arrow, the direct selection tool, I cannot get it to work.

I get an error message:

"the selection contains objects which can't be distorted"

Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Objects

[image]

Included https://www.flickr.com/photos/124549715@N04/

Comment: What's in the selection?

Comment: two images . a circle and a picture

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: thank u for suggession. here it is https://www.flickr.com/photos/124549715@N04/

Answer (score 1):

Select the picture in the background, and then on the top toolbar hit the "Embed" button:

[image: Example of how to embed an image]

You can now envelope distort using the method you were trying to use earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're trying to distort placed or embedded? I get that error message when trying to distort objects placed from outside the document. Try copying the image and pasting it into Illustrator.

Comment: thank u. First , i copy image then i paste into the Illustrator and i make a blue circle and chose both of them. And Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Objects . it informs that "this action require mutil....."

Comment: Is the blue circle in front of the image? If it is bheind, it won't work.

Comment: yes . it is front of the image. but it still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Select the image you want to distort. Object>rasterize. Done!

Comment: You answer is very short.Can you add an image?  BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: ermm... if you look at the question the object **is** a raster image.